# How to add basemaps to spatraster plot with ggplot 2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra

I want to add this basemap  using to raster using ggplot2 and terra packages and I am stuck.
Can I have some help figuring this out?

```
library(basemaps)
library(terra)
Library(rasterVis)

set_defaults(Yiel_total , map_service = "esri" , map_type = "world_hillshade")
x <- basemap_magic(Yiel_total , map_service = "esri" , map_type = "world_hillshade")
#Yiel_total was used for the extent
```

[image]

[SpatRaster Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OseTv3IrZuHr4lWoafex_sAI2NAOKhDZ/view?usp=sharing) for Yiel_total

The ggplot code:

```
Yield <-rast("Yield_total")
Yield_Tot_6 <- gplot(Yield ) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + ggtitle("")+
  theme(panel.spacing.x=unit(0,"lines"), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 18, face = "bold"),strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", face = "bold"),legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.1, size = 16, face = "bold"), panel.background = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title = "Relative yield",title.hjust = 0.5, barheight = 15, barwidth = 2))+ 
  #basemap_magic(Yield_0.5_6, map_service = "esri" , map_type = "world_hillshade")+
  
  facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 3 ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0.01,0.88),low = 'red', high = 'dark green', na.value = "grey93", breaks = c(0.02,0.20, 0.40, 0.60,0.75, 0.87))

Yield_Tot_6
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you commented out the `basemap_magic` layer in your plot code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyterra` to work easily with `ggplot2` and SpatRasters. I modified the call to `basemap_raster` and converted it also to SpatRaster:

```r
library(basemaps)
library(terra)

Yiel_total <- rast("Yiel_total.tif")


set_defaults(Yiel_total, map_service = "esri", map_type = "world_hillshade")
x <- basemap_raster(Yiel_total, map_service = "esri", map_type = "world_hillshade")
x_terr <- rast(x)


library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = x_terr) +
  geom_spatraster(data = Yiel_total) +
  # Faceting with tidyterra
  facet_wrap(~lyr, ncol = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    limits = c(0.01, 0.88), low = "red", high = "dark green",
    na.value = NA, breaks = c(0.02, 0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.75, 0.87)
  ) +
  ggtitle("") +
  theme(
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "lines"), axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(
      hjust = 0.5,
      size = 18, face = "bold"
    ), strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.1, size = 16, face = "bold"), 
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(
    title = "Relative yield", title.hjust = 0.5,
    barheight = 15, barwidth = 2
  ))
```

[image]